# NHibernate generates an invalid table name with SqlCe inserts

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to do a fairly simple insert using NHibernate into a SqlCe database, but it seems that NHibernate is generating wrong table name. It throws GenericADOException with the following details:

> could not insert:
>   [WebLibrary.Models.Category#400a532d-f62e-4faf-978b-a29c00d4de46]
>   [SQL: INSERT INTO WebLibrary.Models_Categories (Title, Slug, DateCreated,
>   LastModified, CreatedBy, LastModifiedBy, ParentId, Id) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]

Here is the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping schema="WebLibrary.Models" assembly="WebLibrary" namespace="WebLibrary.Models" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Category" table="Categories">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid">
      <column name="Id" not-null="true" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
  ...
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And here is the configuration:

```
   var cfg = new Configuration();
   cfg.DataBaseIntegration(c =>
   {
      c.Dialect<MsSqlCe40Dialect>();
      c.ConnectionString =
          "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\library.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
   })
   .AddAssembly(typeof(NHibernateConfiguration).Assembly);
```

As you can see NHibernate is using the full qualified name of the class as the name of the table.

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.1.4000 with SqlCe 4.0.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping contains a `schema` attribute. Remove that.

Adding a schema will prefix the table with the schema name.. which isn't required for tables in the default schema.